# SDE 10.1 Layers Not Loading in ArcGIS Engine Application

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-engine

I have an ArcGIS application that works great when loading layers from SDE 10.0 but fails when trying to load the layers when they're pointing to a SDE 10.1 server.

The only difference is the layer source in the MXD. When the layer points to the SDE 10.0 server, everything loads as expected. If I change the layer source to point to the exact same layer (name, rows, etc.; it was merely copied over from 10.0 to 10.1) in the SDE 10.1 server, a red exclamation point appears next to the layer name.

- The SDE 10.1 layers are visible in ArcMap so this shouldn't be a port or instance issue
- This isn't a licensing issue; I have the app set to exit if the license is invalid/unavailable

Is there something special I need to do to get an Engine application to communicate with an SDE 10.1 server?

Is this a service file issue? I tried adding a reference to the service name and port for the new server in the services file but it didn't seem to help, but 10.0 and 10.1 seem to do services/instances a little differently; perhaps I'm missing something.

UPDATE: The more I think about this, the more it seems to be a "direct connect" issue. Is it possible that I'm not connecting to SDE because things aren't set up right on the client? If so, how do I set up direct connect on an ArcGIS Engine client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ArcGIS Desktop defaults to a direct connection when connecting to SDE starting with 10.1, you need to make sure that your clients have the appropriate SQL Server Native Client installed.

Since we are running SQL Server 2012 we downloaded the native client portion of the [SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065). After installing it on the client, the application was able to load layers from SDE 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy ArcSDE 10.1 client files in arcengine folder , like you have done for arcgis desktop folder.

Comment: Which arcengine folder are you referring to?

Comment: C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Engine10.1\bin

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. I copied the contents of the bin folder to the same path as my executable and there was no change.